# Namespace blank when adding Entity Framework model to Visual Studio website project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6

I am using Visual Studio 2017. And the project type in question is website (project type Guid E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A). This project has `app_code` and `app_data` folders.

[project type list](https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)

I added an ADO.net entity data model using code first to this project and the add wizard prompted me to save/add the created files in the `app_code` in that project. I clicked yes to that.

But when the `DbContext` file and the associated models were added, the namespace was blank in all the newly added files which caused syntax errors.

This is how it looked

```
namespace 
{
    using System;
    ...

    [Table("Phone")]
    public partial class Phone
    { 
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Tseng Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Don't put your model into the `App_Code` directory - create a separate `Models` folder and create your model classes and db context in there - they'll have the proper namespaces

Comment: @marc_s Didnt work. Namespace is still blank

Comment: Looks like it is a bug with entity code first when added to asp.net web form